# Prove an equality of complex matrixes

Tags: matrices, determinant

> If $A \in M_2(\mathbb{C})$ a matrix so that $$\det\left(A^2 + A +
>  I_2\right)=\det\left(A^2 - A + I_2\right)=3 \tag1$$ then $$A^2\left(A^2 + I_2\right)=2I_2. \tag2$$

---

I tried to use Cayley-Hamilton theorem, without success. I think one step might be to prove $A$ is invertible.

Meanwhile I found (2) is equivalent to:
$\left(A^2 -I_2\right)\left(A^2 +2I_2\right)=O_2. \tag3$

Comment: Are you sure there is no any other condition missing?

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes, I'm sure

Comment: Ok, I can't see how it helps, but you mentioned it so pay attention to the fact that condition (2) means $\;A^2\;$ is invertible and thus also $\;A\;$ is.

Comment: Right, I also mentioned that

Comment: So the step you mentioned at the end of your question is already there...

Comment: @DonAntonio What's wrong with that?

Comment: Nothing at all, but you wrote that "one step may be to prove $\;A\;$ is invertible", and you already have that. I thouhgt you wrote the above as you had some idea to use it to prove what you want...I still can't see the way.

Comment: @DonAntonio No, I don't have it, it's in the conclusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, observe that if $A$ satisfies either (1) or (2), then so does $TAT^{-1}$. Thus it suffices to discuss this for $A$ in Jordan normal form, and this we can do by a brute force calculation. We have the conditions
$$
(\lambda_1^2+\lambda_1+1)(\lambda_2^2+\lambda_2+1)= (\lambda_1^2-\lambda_1+1)(\lambda_2^2-\lambda_2+1)= 3 \quad\quad\quad\quad (3)
$$
on the eigenvalues of $A$. It's easy to check that these can not be satisfied with $\lambda_2=\lambda_1$, so $A$ is in fact diagonalizable. If we write $\lambda_2=d/\lambda_1$ and subtract the two resulting order $4$ equations for $\lambda_1$, we see that $\lambda_1=0$ or $\lambda_1^2=-d$. We can easily rule out the first alternative. It then follows that $\lambda_2=-\lambda_1$, so, returning to (3), we obtain that
$$
(\lambda^2+\lambda+1)(\lambda^2-\lambda+1)= 3 ,
$$
or, equivalently $\lambda^2(\lambda^2+1)=2$
for both $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, and this is what we wanted to show.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Equation $(1)$ implies that either $tr(A)=0$ or $\det(A)=-1$. Using Cayley-Hamilton, we obtain in both cases (together with $(1)$ again) that $(A^2-I)(A^2 +2I)=0$.

Comment: How do I prove $tr(A)=0$ or $\det(A)=-1$? Please elaborate a bit more